# Opencart 1.5.4 - Customer Order Confirmation emails not sent

Tags: email, opencart

We are sending emails via a Gmail account that is set up in our Mail tab in settings. All admin emails are going out but our customers are saying that they are not receiving a confirmation email. Is there a place where you can turn on and off customer confirmation emails? Since we switched to Gmail and set up the mail tab correctly the error log doesn't show anything.

We need to know why our emails will go to admin from the site but not go to our customers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to tick yes on **New Order Alert Mail:** and **New Account Alert Mail:** at mail tab.